# sed: replacing end of line

Tags: bash, sed, eol

I need to quote end of line and using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/395616) solution to replace end of line which working perfectly when file has multiple lines.

Problem arises when I try to use this method with files that have no `\n` or have single line ending with `\n`. In this case `sed` does not replace anything, even second `s/` command does not work. Also looks like last end of line is never replaced.

My command is:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' <file>
```

*(replace `\n` to `\\n` and replace `a` to `_` for example).*

I use `hexdump -C` to display files here:

There are tests I made:

```
$ # Test1. single line without \n
$ echo -n 'abc' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63                                          |abc|
# but expected "_bc"

$ # Test2. single line with \n
$ echo 'abc' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 0a                                       |abc.|
# but expected "_bc\n"

$ # Test3. two lines
$ echo -e 'abc\n' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | hexdump -C
00000000  5f 62 63 5c 6e 0a                                 |_bc\n.|
# but expected "_bc\n\n"
```

**Questions:** Why second `s/` does not replace anything in Test1 and Test2? Is there any method to fix replacing of `s/\n/\\n/` and `s/a/_/g` in all this tests?

P.S.: I don't want some workaround like adding newline at end of stream before sed processing and removing it after.

**EDIT:** looks like `N` command does not read single line, even if it followed by '\n'. Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT2:** Seems like this is [expected behavior of `N` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86995/44107). Is there any method on how to replace last line ending?

Comment: I used this recently: sed '{:q;N;s/\n/_/g;t q}'

Comment: Have you tried separating the sed parts? `sed ':a;N;$!ba' <file> | sed 's/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g'` or similar.

Comment: This does not help, because it is equal to `cat <file> | sed 's/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g'`. Joining lines using `':a;N;$!ba'` is working just within one sed process.

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' <file> | sed 's/a/_/g'` ? Or I'm out of suggestions, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not replace end of line. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad, but I don't find any method to prevent sed from adding new line to output when `N` command is used. I didn't want to some workaround to like add new line before processing and removing it after, but seems like there is no other method.

This is the final solution with workaround:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' <<< "$VAR" | tr -d '\n'
```

`<<<` like echo adds new line into input string, `tr` removes it.

With that line all test are OK:

```
$ echo -e "abc" | sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | tr -d '\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  5f 62 63                                          |_bc|

$ echo -e "abc\n" | sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | tr -d '\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  5f 62 63 5c 6e                                    |_bc\n|

$ echo -e "abc\n\n" | sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' | tr -d '\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  5f 62 63 5c 6e 5c 6e                              |_bc\n\n|
```

P.S.: thanks potong for figuring out the `:a;$!{N;ba}`.

P.P.S.: If someone will give working answer without `tr`, I will re-accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' file
```

or:

```
sed ':a;$!N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;y/a/_/' file
```

Logically it makes sense: one cannot get the `next` line if you are on the `last` line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the logic. Unfortunately it does not replace last end of line to '\\n' (Test2 and Test3). Possibly there is no solution to make `N` read don't skip last line.

Comment: As it cannot read a line that does not exist just add one! `sed ':a;$!{N;ba};G;s/\n/\\n/g;s/a/_/g' file

Comment: Unfortunately, this always adds new line into source stream, so Test1 is failed. Also it does not remove last end line, so all tests are failed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `perl` instead?

```
$ echo -n "abc" | perl -pe 's/\n$/\\n/;' -pe 's/a/_a/;' | od -x
0000000 615f 6362
0000004
$ echo "abc" | perl -pe 's/\n$/\\n/;' -pe 's/a/_a/;' | od -x
0000000 615f 6362 6e5c
0000006
$ echo -e 'abc\n' | perl -pe 's/\n$/\\n/;' -pe 's/a/_a/;' | od -x
0000000 615f 6362 6e5c 6e5c
0000010
```

Comment: Bash is strongly preferred. Don't want to add new dependency just for one script of >30.

Comment: @loentar Do you have a character that doesn't appear in your input :)

Comment: I'm sorry, had typos in "expected results", your second regex should look like `'s/a/_/;'`, also it can be combined into single argument: `perl -pe 's/\n$/\\n/g;s/a/_/g'`. Thank you for answer anyway.